# WYSIWYG Responsive( Adaptive, Fluid, etc, ...) Image in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, inline

How can I make inline Images ( Images used in the text of article ) responsive in Drupal 7.( I use Wysiwg and CKEditor). I can make Image Field files responsive with Adaptive Image Module but apparently it doesn't have any option for doing such action for inline images.

Other module like Picture and some thing like that make Image styles for different styles of theme( breakpoints indeed) but I want to make may image adaptive with all resolutions in other word I want all of my images be fluid, not conditional.The http://www.fastcompany.com have the best image styles in my opinion and I want exactly this behavior for my project.

For more information I studied all forums in Drupal.org about this issue but I can't find any reliable solution.

TNX

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css (make to fit your own css rules for wanted images):

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```